# visual studio data provider error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, objectdataprovider

whenever I click on my database .dbml file in visual studio2010 ultimate, I get the error - visual studio has encountered an unexpected error - does anyone know what could be causing this. the same project works well on a different machine. I suspect its the dataprovider file but I'm not sure how to reinstall this.

Comment: Have you looked in your system event logs to see if any errors are noted?

Comment: Did you installed all the database drivers and also added all references needed ?